# sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < ~/id_rsa.pub | error: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, git, bash

> I got this shell script from a blog about how to equip git with gitosis.
>   But i got a "No such file or directory" error after running the script.

```
[git@209285 ~]$ sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < ~/id_rsa.pub
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gitosis-init", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gitosis==0.2', 'console_scripts', 'gitosis-init')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/app.py", line 24, in run
    return app.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/app.py", line 38, in main
    self.handle_args(parser, cfg, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/init.py", line 138, in handle_args
    user=user,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/init.py", line 75, in init_admin_repository
    template=resource_filename('gitosis.templates', 'admin')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/repository.py", line 63, in init
    close_fds=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am puzzled,as the man manual says that:

```
  -H          The -H (HOME) option sets the HOME environment variable to the homedir of the target user (root by default) as specified in passwd(5).  By default, sudo
           does not modify HOME (see set_home and always_set_home in sudoers(5)).
```

,which is cited from linux manual.

**The -H option just sets the HOME environment variable to the homedir of the target user as specified in passwd.**

However i specified "/home/git" as homedir for git user in my /etc/passwd file.

```
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin
git:x:100:101:git version control:/home/git:/bin/bash
duanduan:x:101:500::/home/duanduan:/bin/bash
```

But why i still got this message? or was incorrect my comprehension of the description in manual?

---

**Append for comments:**

And it seems like before with specifying a absolute path.Maybe, it's not the cause.

```
 sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /home/git/id_rsa.pub
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gitosis-init", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gitosis==0.2', 'console_scripts', 'gitosis-init')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/app.py", line 24, in run
    return app.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/app.py", line 38, in main
    self.handle_args(parser, cfg, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/init.py", line 138, in handle_args
    user=user,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/init.py", line 75, in init_admin_repository
    template=resource_filename('gitosis.templates', 'admin')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/repository.py", line 63, in init
    close_fds=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Note: gitosis is obsolete since 2009. Consider using gitolite: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is because `~` is expanded by bash before transferring to `sudo` as a argument, why not try to specify a absolute path for you public key file?

Comment: Or `~git/id_rsa.pub` if that's what you want.  Your question isn't really clear.

Comment: It also seems like before with specifying a absolute path.Maybe it's not the cause.   ```